# C++: Error C2065, C2131, a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to make a program that get user's integer input and then filter every single digit in that int into even number and odd number. There is no any mistake when I finished the code but error comes out when I run it.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int input = NULL;
    int EvenNumbering = 0;
    int OddNumbering = 0;

    cout << "Please input a number: ";
    cin >> input;

    string str = to_string(input); //Convert it to string
    char cstr[str.length];
    int EvenNo[str.length];
    int OddNo[str.length];

    strcpy(cstr , str.c_str()); //Put it into char array

    //Now filter Even number and Odd number
    for (string x : cstr) {
        int z = stoi(x);
        if (z % 2 == 0) {
            EvenNo[EvenNumbering] += z;
            EvenNumbering++;
        }
        else {
            OddNo[OddNumbering] += z;
            OddNumbering++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Even Numbers: ";

    for (int x : EvenNo) {
        cout << x << ", ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Odd Numbers: ";

    for (int x : OddNo) {
        cout << x << ", ";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My error:

```
source.cpp(18): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
source.cpp(18): note: a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered
source.cpp(19): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
source.cpp(19): note: a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered
source.cpp(20): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
source.cpp(20): note: a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered
source.cpp(26): error C2065: 'x': undeclared identifier
source.cpp(40): error C2065: 'x': undeclared identifier
source.cpp(47): error C2065: 'x': undeclared identifier
1>Done building project "Question.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Still new to C++ and this is my first Project so please forgive me if I did some beginner mistake.

Comment: Try using `std::vector` instead of C style arrays. (int name[size]) it will save you a lot of issues.

Comment: `char cstr[str.length];` -- This is not legal C++.  If you want a dynamic array, use `std::vector<char>`.  Also, it is a good thing you're using a compiler that gives this error.  Too many C++ newbies use a brand of compiler that allows this syntax, thus they wind up thinking what they wrote is valid C++.

Comment: Also, why use char arrays such as `cstr`?  Just stick with all character data being a `std::string`.  Then you don't need the unnecessary `strcpy`.

Comment: `char cstr[str.length]`, `int EvenNo[str.length];` and `int OddNo[str.length];` are called a "variable length array" (VLA). It is a GCC extension. You need to find the MSVC equivalent. You should consider using a `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three lines are not legal C++ syntax:

```
char cstr[str.length];
int EvenNo[str.length];
int OddNo[str.length];
```

The first error to point out is that the `length()` function is a function, not a property.  Thus the syntax would be `str.length()` (note the parentheses to denote a function call).

But beyond that, arrays in C++ must be declared using a constant expression to denote the number of entries, and not a runtime derived value.

The way that dynamic arrays are done in C++ (or the most preferred way) is to use `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
//...
string str = to_string(input); //Convert it to string
std::vector<char> cstr(str.length());
std::vector<int> EvenNo(str.length());
std::vector<int> OddNo(str.length());
```

Also, there really is no need for `cstr`.  The next line will cause a failure, now that `cstr` is a `vector<char>`:

```
strcpy(cstr , str.c_str()); //Put it into char array
```

Since `cstr` is no longer an array of `char`, this will not (or should not) compile.  The way to solve it is to get rid of `cstr` altogether, and just use `str` throughout your program.

However, if you insisted on keeping the `std::vector<char>`, then the following will work, but really you should just get rid of `cstr`.  But here goes:

```
strcpy(&cstr[0] , str.c_str()); //Put it into char array
```

The following would also have worked if `cstr` remained an array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (a problem) is here:

```
string str = to_string(input); //Convert it to string
char cstr[str.length];
int EvenNo[str.length];
int OddNo[str.length];
```

The `str` string is initialized run-time, so its length can't be known compile-time.

But `str.lenght` is used to set the dimension of three C-style arrays.

In C++ (the standard versions) the size of a C-style arrays **must** be known compile time.

Suggestion: use `std::vector` for `cstr`, `EvenNo` and `OddNo`